# Java/Android Calendar, add 1 week on Sundays

Tags: android, calendar, java.util.calendar

OK, so my code has worked good until the day became Sunday.

I'm working on an app that uses the Calendar util allot, so it functioning the way i think it does is important to me! The problem:

```
    import java.util.Calendar;

    ...

    Calendar test = Calendar.getInstance();

    test.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);

    Log.e("WEEEK TEST:", ""+ test.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));

    test.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);

    Log.e("WEEEK TEST:", ""+ test.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

Outputs this:

```
     06-01 14:04:07.636  12005-12005/test.app E/WEEEK TEST:﹕ 23
     06-01 14:04:07.636  12005-12005/test.app E/WEEEK TEST:﹕ 23
```

How can this even happen, and how do i fix it?

Comment: Is your device date and time correct? Did you make that test today?

Comment: Yes i tested it today, but i don't think it matters how my phone is configured because I'm adding a week, which should add a week whatever the date on my phone is. Shouldn't it? How can this week be 23, and then in a week, it's also week 23?

Comment: I found a "hack": One has to add -1, then add 1 week, before using the Calendar after setFirstDayOfWeek().

Comment: Then, you must explain your hack as an answer. It's a hack, yet it is still a solution. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Calendar test = Calendar.getInstance();
test.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
test.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
test.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
```

Now "test" should work correctly